# Is there a general solution to $\int e^{F(x)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, algebra-precalculus

Is there a general solution to $\int e^{F(x)}dx$, where $F'(x)=f(x)$? What should one do if one has an integral of this form, without having any real constraints on $F(x)$?

Comment: What's with $F(x)=-x^2$? This is impossible.

Comment: Any  $ G(x)$  that takes only positive values is equal to $e^{F(x)}$ where $F(x)=\ln G(x).$ There is no general "formula" for integrating positive functions and some deep theorems on why this is so.

Comment: So a general solution for the integral of a generic positive and differentiable function? I doubt that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no constraints on $F$, then nothing can be done. For example, if $F(x)=x^2$, then the integral becomes the famously non-elementary $$\int e^{x^2}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Take $F(x) = \arctan x$ we know It is not to express

$$\int e^{\arctan x}dx $$
as elementary functions.

Answer (score 2):

[Impossibility theorems for elementary integration](https://wstein.org/edu/winter06/20b/Conrad.pdf)